# Valgrind: "invalid read size 1" when throwing custom exception

Tags: c++, exception, valgrind

My program works fine except when I run it in valgrind and make it throw an exception(I do it on purpose, it depends on user-defined parameters).

The main function is:

```
int main(){
 try{
        // create objects
        // call function 
 }
 catch(std::exception const& e){
     std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

and I don't use any other "try ... catch" block in the code.

I defined my own Exception class:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED
#define CUSTOMEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED

#include <exception>


class TracedError : public std::exception
{      
  protected:
    int line_;
    std::string file_;
    std::string description;

  public:
    TracedError(std::string const& file, int line, std::string const& desc)
    throw():
    line_(line),
        file_(file),
        description(desc)
    {}

     virtual const char* what() const throw(){
    std::string msg;
    msg = "File: " + file_ + " Line: " + std::to_string(line_) + " Message: " + description;
        return msg.c_str();
     }

    virtual ~TracedError() throw() {}
};


#endif // CUSTOMEXCEPTION_H_INCLUDED
```

And I call exceptions like this:

```
throw TracedError(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Message of the exception");
```

There is no problem when I compile and run the program, an exception appears under this form:

```
ERROR: File: path/to/file.cpp Line: 106 Message: Message of the exception.
```

which is exactly what I want. But when I run this with valgrind, I get an error:

```
ERROR: ==12664== Invalid read of size 1
==12664==    at 0x4C2CC02: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12664==    by 0x4ECED58: length (char_traits.h:263)
==12664==    by 0x4ECED58: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (ostream:536)
==12664==    by 0x441EC6: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664==  Address 0x5a20b88 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 237 free'd
==12664==    at 0x4C2B183: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12664==    by 0x4422E1: TracedError::what() const (TracedError.h:25)
==12664==    by 0x441EA9: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664== 
==12664== Invalid read of size 1
==12664==    at 0x4C2CC14: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12664==    by 0x4ECED58: length (char_traits.h:263)
==12664==    by 0x4ECED58: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (ostream:536)
==12664==    by 0x441EC6: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664==  Address 0x5a20b89 is 25 bytes inside a block of size 237 free'd
==12664==    at 0x4C2B183: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12664==    by 0x4422E1: TracedError::what() const (TracedError.h:25)
==12664==    by 0x441EA9: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664== 
==12664== Syscall param write(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==12664==    at 0x5753940: __write_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==12664==    by 0x56DBD2C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1302)
==12664==    by 0x56DC4EE: new_do_write (fileops.c:537)
==12664==    by 0x56DC4EE: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1384)
==12664==    by 0x56D1E68: fwrite (iofwrite.c:43)
==12664==    by 0x4ECE955: sputn (streambuf:451)
==12664==    by 0x4ECE955: __ostream_write<char, std::char_traits<char> > (ostream_insert.h:50)
==12664==    by 0x4ECE955: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (ostream_insert.h:101)
==12664==    by 0x4ECED66: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (ostream:535)
==12664==    by 0x441EC6: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664==  Address 0x5a20b88 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 237 free'd
==12664==    at 0x4C2B183: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12664==    by 0x4422E1: TracedError::what() const (TracedError.h:25)
==12664==    by 0x441EA9: main (main.cpp:52)
==12664== 
File: /home/ak/Documents/framework-v3/src/encoder.cpp Line: 106 Message: The evolution parameters are incorrect.
==12664== 
==12664== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12664==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12664==   total heap usage: 26 allocs, 26 frees, 1,292 bytes allocated
==12664== 
==12664== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12664== 
==12664== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12664== ERROR SUMMARY: 114 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

main.cpp: 52 refers to this line:

```
std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
```

and TracedError.h:25 refers to this line:

```
return msg.c_str();
```

From what I understand, it returns an invalid pointer. But it compiles fine outside of valgrind and prints the right message.

Is it because I don't use "try ... catch" blocks in the other classes/ functions ? Should I systematically catch and re-throw errors ?

It seems like a lot of code to add for something that already works, so my question is: does that mean that I've got an undefined behavior which may cause havock or can I ignore the valgrind error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, it returns an invalid pointer. But it compiles fine outside of valgrind and prints the right message.

That doesn't mean much. You have undefined behavior, thus anything can happen (including that it seems to work as expected).

`return msg.c_str();` returns the pointer from a local variable, that ceases to exist after `TracedError::what()` was called. That's the reason why valgrind complains.

You should make `msg` a member variable of the exception class and build the message string in the constructor to fix this.

Comment: Thank you, I tried and tested, it works fine. That's much simpler than what I thought !